# An interesting equality regarding a line through the centroid of a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

$G$ is the intersection of the medians of $\triangle{ABC}$, and $K$ and $L$ are points on $AB$ and $AC$, respectively, such that $G$ is a point on $KL$. The line determined by $K$ and $L$ intersect the line determined by $B$ and $C$ at $P$. If $C$ is between $B$ and $P$,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{KG}
= \frac{1}{LG}
+ \frac{1}{GP} .
\end{equation*}

[image]

Comment: $\overline{KM}$ represents a line segment. The length of that line segment is $KM$. So, I think you meant $\frac{1}{KM}+\frac{1}{LM}+\frac{1}{MP}$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Have you perhaps somehow participated at EGMO in Florence

Comment: @ChristianF: not in person, but I assisted the preparation of the event in the previous months.

Comment: @steven gregory   I have always used $\vert \overline{AB} \vert$ to represent the length of a line segment $\overline{AB}$, and I am imitating the notation used by authors of many geometry textbooks. I understand that the notation you are suggesting is also common.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I see that you have edited my post and provided a diagram. Thanks.

Comment: @user74973: I find such notation utterly redundant, since in writing $\frac{1}{AB}$ it is pretty clear that we mean the reciprocal of the length of $AB$. What else?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I wouldn't say the notation that I prefer is "redundant." It is an emphasis.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Do you have an alternate solution to the one offered by ChristianF?

Comment: @user74973: not really. One may use cross-ratios or ratios of areas, but ultimately all these approaches are equivalent to Menelaus'/Ceva's theorems.

Comment: You can also try coordinate system.:(

Comment: @ChristianF  I prefer to have an explanation couched in Euclidean Geometry. I am sure the one you provided is quite suitable.

Comment: There is also another approach. You can try and solve it with vectors or complex numbers, but you will also have to use Menelaus theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $KG=x$, $GL =y$ and $LP =z$. Then we have to prove $y^2+zy =2xy+xz$.

Also let $R$ halves $BC=2a$ and mark $CP=b$.

Now, if we apply Menelaus theorem twice on triangle $GRP$

first on transversal $B-K-A$ we get $${b+2a\over a}\cdot {3\over 2}\cdot {x\over x+y+z}=1$$ and second on transversal $C-L-A$ we get $${b\over a}\cdot {3\over 2}\cdot {y\over z}=1$$
and eliminating ${b\over a}$ from both, you will get a desired formula.

Comment: Please clarify in your response "$R$ halves $BC = 2a$.  (I will erase this comment.)

Comment: R is a midpoint of BC and let 2a be the lenght of BC

Comment: I had not seen an application of Menelaus' Theorem in the case that the "transversal line" does not intersect the triangle.  Very nice!